# Print 1 When Switch Date to Arabic

Tags: php, switch-statement, arabic

Hello i Make Code To Convert The Day Name To Arabic with session and date("L")

Like When Day is Friday , Print Day in Arabic = " الجمعه "

when i echo $nameday , his just print a 1

```
    <?php

$nameday = date("L");

switch($nameday) {

 case "Saturday":
    $nameday = "ألسبت";
    break;


     case "Sunday":
    $nameday = "الأحد";
    break;

     case "Monday":
    $nameday = "الأثنين";
    break;    

     case "Tuesday":
    $nameday = "الثلاثاء";
    break;

     case "Wednesday":
    $nameday = "الأربعاء";
    break;

     case "Thursday":
    $nameday = "الخميس";
    break;


     case "Friday":
    $nameday = "الجمعه";
    break;


}

echo $nameday;
?>
```

Comment: Uppercase `L` gives you whether it's a leap-year: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php You want `date('l')`, or lowercase `L`. Demo: http://codepad.org/JfSCZGsL

Comment: date("l"); use lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want complete week day name by using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) than you need to use lower `l (L)` as:

```
$nameday = date("l");
```

**Lower case (l)** is use for full textual representation of the week day name.

**Side note:**

For Arabic language make sure you are saving your file as `utf8 encoded`.

Comment: thanx but what his print the arabic like " ?#!#?" not orginal text